# como hacer para que en esta linea se lea la tecla delete atras

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

Estoy usando esta linea para que en un TextBox solo sea números lo que lea pero cuando le hago a borrar  con la tecla de atrás lee como si fuera una letra;
como hago para solucionarlo :

```
 Private Sub txt_id_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txt_id.KeyPress
        If Not Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) Then
            e.Handled = False
            MessageBox.Show("Introduzca sólo valores númericos")
        End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Buenas Fabro,

Puedes usar lo siguiente:

```
 Private Sub txt_id_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txt_id.KeyPress
        If Not Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) And e.KeyChar <> ControlChars.Back Then
            e.Handled = False
            MessageBox.Show("Introduzca sólo valores númericos")
        End If
```

Comment: mae muchas gracias!!

Comment: @fabro considera aceptar la respuesta si te solucionó tu pregunta. Un saludo y bienvenido a [es.so]